# Computing average value of d3 force layout node's co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am still a newbie with javascript and d3. I wanted to compute the average value of d3 force layout node's co-ordinates (remember that these nodes are flexible, i.e. can be moved around with mouse drag). I saw the usage of `.map` in one of the answers and tried using it but there seems to be some problem. Right now my code snippet looks like this:

```
        function tick() {
          var positions = finalNodeSet.map(function(d) { 
          return [d.x, d.y]; 
        });

        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<positions.length; i++){
            x1+=positions[[i][0]];
            y1+=positions[[i][1]]; 
            }
```

It seems that `positions` is of type `object` and it contains all the co-ordinates of all the nodes with every 'tick'. Now what I would desire is to store just the final values of the coordinates and get the average value of the co-ordinates. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
 link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

        node.each(collide(.5))
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });

    }
```

Comment: No idea what `finalNodeSet` is. Can you show us the code you're using to set the positions of the nodes inside the `tick` handler?

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me: I do not require the x, y coordinates of the last two nodes(as they have a fixed value) and thus the exclusion.

```
var positions = finalNodeSet.map(function(d) { 

            return [d.x, d.y]; 


        });
        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;
        var xbar=0;
        var ybar=0;

        for(var i=0; i<positions.length-2 ; i++){
            x1+=positions[[i]][0];
            y1+=positions[[i]][1];

            var xbar=x1/positions.length-2;

            var ybar=y1/positions.length-2;
            }

            ax1=positions[positions.length-2][0];
            ay1=positions[positions.length-2][1];
            ax2=positions[positions.length-1][0];
            ay1=positions[positions.length-1][1];
```